# How to correctly configure Spring Security into my project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubts about how correctly configure **Spring Security**.

Into the study material I found these informations that seems to me not so clear.

It say that:

**Configuration in the Application Context:**

- **Spring configuration**
- **Using Spring Security's "Security" namespace**

and it show the following example:

```
<beans>
    <security:http>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/accounts/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.htm"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/index.html"/>
   </security:http>
</beans>
```

Then in the following slide it say:

**Configuration in web.xml:**

Define the single proxy filter:

- **springSecurityFilterChain is a mandatory name**
- **Refers to an existing Spring bean with same name**

and show this example:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I can't understand if, to configure Spring Security inside a Spring project, I have to use both these configuration: the first one into the Spring configuration file (where I define my bean) and the second one into the **web.xml** file (that defines everything about your application that a server needs to know: servlets, filters, initializaztion paramters and so on...) or if these example are 2 different alternatives to do the same things in 2 differents way?

If it is the second case when have I to use the first one and when have I to use the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do two things :

- configure the security over your http request (in applicationContext)
- configure your application container to be aware of your security configuration using the web.xml

So slides are two steps, not two alternatives.

EDIT : 
The first step will allow you to configure which url will be secured and which will not be secured (and more option)

The second is the step which allow your configuration to be apply to your app

I hope it may help you

Comment: Yes it helps but you can give more information about what exactly does these 2 steps?